# WMP9 skin for mplayer

Tags: linux, mplayer, skin

I want my wife to use Linux but she likes only how Windows Media Player 9 looks (not 10 or 11). Does anybody knows about good looking WMP9-like skin for mplayer?

Comment: Why does it have to be mplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason it has to be mplayer? Since I think it will be easier to find a good skin for VLC (more widely supported).

HowToGeek wrote a [nice tutorial on how to do so](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/make-vlc-player-look-like-windows-media-player-11/), however his example is Windows Media Player 11

[image]

Perhaps you should check out his link to [the official VLC skin page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php).

Or you could just [install Windows Media Player 9 under Linux with Wine.](http://www.wine-reviews.net/microsoft/windows-media-player-9-aamp-10-on-linux-with-wine.html)